# VBA Compare 2 arrays and return missing rows INCLUDING DUPLICATES

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

Every morning I have to **compare manually row by row** the information in **my database with** the one **sent by the broker**. Normally they **should have exactly the same information**.
The information is about executed trades.

1- I need to compare row by row looking at the values **"Stock", "Qty", "Price" and "Date"**. If any **row is not matched** from each other (i.e. a value is erroneously different in one of the table or the entire row is missing), I need the **unmatched rows to** be printed in a **third "OUTPUT" table**.

My TABLE, BROKER'S TABLE & OUTPUT

[image]

2- The thing here is that **there are duplicates** like for "microsoft" or "nvidia" that are **independent trades** (different IDs). **Duplicates must be kept** in the comparison because they are different trades.

How could I manage the duplicates problems? Using **Collections in Dictionary** could help me? I would compare Table A to Table B and then Table B to Table A.
Or the presence of duplicates (actually independent trades) makes it impossible to perform ?

My file has more than 500 rows.

Comment: Using a dictionary will help you get rid of duplicates, so not what you want.

Comment: If this information is coming from a database, could you not run a query on the database to get this information?

Comment: Can you paste text data for both tables? This would help to create sample sheets. Have you tried to write VBA procedure?

Comment: All this can be performed using Excel spreadsheet functions, without having to use VBA. Create a "hash" of each line (in both) tables: that is a string comprised of stock, quantity, price and size. You can run through table A, using the MATCH(...,0) function to check if it exists in table B. And vice-versa for table B. This will weed out trades that are in one table and not the other. For the remainder, use a COUNTIF() function to see how many instance of each trade are in each table, then compare those numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! @DS_London I was triying to do this with function N() and MATCH(). The idea was to compare each cell and return True or False in the form of 0 or 1 thanks to N(). I ended up with a matrix array for each row of {1,1,1,0,0} and multiplied the values. A result of 1 = Exact Match and a result of 0 = no Match. With the other function I was able to locate the row adress of the match but that didn't accounted for duplicates. Your solution may be faster and less tedious to perform because of the hash reducing number of comparison to one. I need to check it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add an entirely in-memory way to achieve the output.

The one thing worth considering is that we have no way of differentiating one ID from the next if they have matching stock, price, qty, and dates. So, the way I'm handling duplicates is in the order that they appear in the spreadsheet. So if there are two matching entries in your table, and only 1 in the broker table, I assume that the first entry in your table matches the first entry in the broker table, and therefore your second entry will be output.

Try working through the code. I took a few shortcuts for the sake of timing, but I also encapsulated each of the functions so that you can modify as needed. You'll just have to build out the DeserializeKey function to convert a key back to cells in the output sheet (shouldn't be too hard). See the below code, and let me know if it meets expectations.

Note: You will run the "CompareDictionaries" subroutine. The others are helper functions.

```
Sub CompareDictionaries()
    Dim oMine As Object
    Dim oBroker As Object
    Dim myQueueCount As Long
    Dim brokerQueueCount As Long
    Dim minQueue As Long
    Dim oMinQueue As Object
    
    Set oMine = GetDictionary(Sheet1.Range("A2:E7"))
    Set oBroker = GetDictionary(Sheet2.Range("A2:E6"))
    
    For Each oKey In oMine.keys
        'The whole row does not exist in the broker table
        If Not oBroker.Exists(oKey) Then
            Do While oMine(oKey).Count > 0
                DeserializeKey oKey, oMine(oKey).dequeue
            Loop
        
        Else 'The keys exist in both tables
            myQueueCount = oMine(oKey).Count
            brokerQueueCount = oBroker(oKey).Count
            If myQueueCount = brokerQueueCount Then
                'Do nothing. They both have the same number of
                'id's, and so we assume they are in sync.
            Else
                'Determine the minimum queue size, and get rid
                'of that many values, since we won't need them
                minQueue = IIf(myQueueCount < brokerQueueCount, myQueueCount, brokerQueueCount)
                
                For i = 1 To minQueue
                    oMine(oKey).dequeue
                    oBroker(oKey).dequeue
                Next i
                
                'Take the remaining IDs out of the dictionary/queue that had more
                If brokerQueueCount > myQueueCount Then
                    Set oMinQueue = oBroker
                Else
                    Set oMinQueue = oMine
                End If
                
                Do While oMinQueue(oKey).Count > 0
                    DeserializeKey oKey, oMinQueue(oKey).dequeue
                Loop
            End If
        End If
    Next oKey
    
    'The only remaining thing to test for is keys in the broker dict
    'that are not in the myDict
    For Each oKey In oBroker.keys
        If Not oMine.Exists(oKey) Then
            Do While oBroker(oKey).Count > 0
                DeserializeKey oKey, oBroker(oKey).dequeue
            Loop
        End If
    Next oKey
End Sub


Function GetDictionary(inputRange As Range) As Object
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim theKey As String
    Dim oQueue As Object
    
    Set sht = inputRange.Parent
    
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each cel In Intersect(inputRange, sht.Columns(1))
        theKey = GenerateKey(cel.Resize(, 5))
        
        If oDict.Exists(theKey) Then
            oDict(theKey).enqueue cel.Value
        Else
            Set oQueue = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
            oQueue.enqueue cel.Value
            oDict.Add theKey, oQueue
        End If
    Next cel
    
    Set GetDictionary = oDict
End Function


Sub DeserializeKey(ByVal theKey As String, theId As String)
    'This is where you'd do some stuff to
    'turn the key into individual cells, and store it.
    'I'm only writing to the debug widnow to demonstrate
    
    Debug.Print theId & " " & theKey
End Sub


Function GenerateKey(rng As Range) As String
    GenerateKey = rng(2) & Format(rng(3), "0") _
        & Format(rng(4), "0.00") & Format(rng(5), "mmddyyyy")

End Function
```

**For those interested in this method, I'm editing this answer to add the "deserializekey" function:**

````
  
    
Dim r As Long
Worksheets("Output").Activate

r = 1

'What we are doing here with "loopcell" is to check if the destination cells in the "output" sheet are empty or free.
'If not, we go down 1 row.
loopcell:
If IsEmpty(Range("A" & r).Value) = True Then
    Range("A" & r).Value = "_" & theId & "_" & theKey
Else
r = r + 1
GoTo loopcell
End If

'The key is wrote to the the cell but we need to split every element of the key in multiple cells. 
splitOutput = Range("A" & r).Value
splitArray = Split(splitOutput, "_")

For i = 1 To UBound(splitArray)
Cells(r, i).Value = splitArray(i)
Next i

    Debug.Print theId & " " & theKey
End Sub ```


** New GetDictionary and Deserialize methods used to store more info **

    Sub DeserializeKey(ByVal theKey As String, theId As Variant)
        'This is where you'd do some stuff to
        'turn the key into individual cells, and store it.
        'I'm only writing to the debug widnow to demonstrate
        Dim output As String
        
        'Keep in mind that we have a 2d array, and we are reading
        'one row at a time. So get the number of columns in the
        'array, and then do whatever you need with them.
        For i = LBound(theId, 2) To UBound(theId, 2)
            output = output & " " & theId(1, i)
        Next i
        
        Debug.Print theKey & " -->" & output
    End Sub


    Function GetDictionary(inputRange As Range) As Object
        Dim oDict As Object
        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Dim cel As Range
        Dim theKey As String
        Dim oQueue As Object
        Dim columnCount As Long
        Dim rngAsArray As Variant
        
        Set sht = inputRange.Parent
        
        'Get the column count of the input range. Since we don't
        'hardcode it in, this function is more flexible to
        'future changes
        columnCount = inputRange.Columns.Count
        
        Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        For Each cel In Intersect(inputRange, sht.Columns(1))
            theKey = GenerateKey(cel.Resize(, 5))
            
            'Put the full row into an array, which we will then
            'store as the content of the queue
            rngAsArray = cel.Resize(, columnCount).Value
            
            If oDict.Exists(theKey) Then
                oDict(theKey).enqueue rngAsArray
            Else
                Set oQueue = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
                oQueue.enqueue rngAsArray
                oDict.Add theKey, oQueue
            End If
        Next cel
        
        Set GetDictionary = oDict
    End Function
````

Comment: Than you very much ! I will try this code. I'll keep you updated :-)

Comment: I have a problem with the code. A "runtime error 424 - object is required" occurs. I checked the library Microsoft Scripting Runtime was enabled, checked for typos but nothing. All seems to be ok ...

Comment: It Stops here --> Set oMine = GetDictionary(Sheet1.Range("A2:E7"))

Comment: @Xander, this is where you'll have to update the code to match your workbook. Does your workbook actually have a `Sheet1` (that is the codename). If not, you can define the workbook using the worksheet caption. E.g., if you have a sheet with the caption  "MY TABLE", you can write `Set oMine = GetDictionary(Worksheets("MY TABLE").Range("A1:E7"))`. Obviously, you should try to build your range dynamically so that you are flexible to changes. Let me know if that helps or if you need more help.

Comment: Solved with Set oMine = GetDictionary(**Worksheets("Sheet1")**.Range("A2:E7")) thx !

Comment: @Xander Great. Hopefully you get the whole script working and it suits your needs.

Comment: Big thanks for your code. I'm using it at work and works like a charm !  I just have 1 question about the code. 
`Sub DeserializeKey(ByVal theKey As String, theId As String)
      Debug.Print theId & " " & theKey
End Sub`
In this case "theId" returns me the 1st column that wasn't included in key generation. That's good and ok but I don't Know how this variable "theId" works and how the 1st column is stocked there. It is possible to do the same thing wit more columns? Ex: theId1 & theId2 (another extra column) & theKey

Comment: @Xander Glad to see that it's working. `theId` is originally stored in the queue object in the `GetDictionary` method call. Orignally, the queue's were just used as placeholders, so I just stored a simple value. You have the option of storing the entire row (or relevant fields) in the queue, and then calling them in the deserialize method. I will make an edit with a new `GetDictionary` and new `Deserialize` method to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please read DS_London's comment.

If you would like to have a result sheet, then you can use below macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareData()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wshMyData As Worksheet, wshBrokersData As Worksheet, wshResult As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim sTmp As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set wshResult = wbk.Worksheets("Result")
    
    On Error GoTo Err_CompareData

    'if there_s no result sheet
    If Not wshResult Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wbk.Worksheets("Result").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    Set wshMyData = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wshBrokersData = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set wshResult = wbk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wshBrokersData)
    wshResult.Name = "Result"
    wshResult.Range("A1") = "ID"
    wshResult.Range("B1") = "Stock"
    wshResult.Range("C1") = "Qty"
    wshResult.Range("D1") = "Price"
    wshResult.Range("E1") = "Date"
    wshResult.Range("F1") = "My"
    wshResult.Range("G1") = "Broker"
    wshResult.Range("A1:G1").Interior.Color = vbGreen
    
    'find last entry in your data
    i = wshMyData.Range("A" & wshMyData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'find last entry in brokers data
    j = wshBrokersData.Range("A" & wshBrokersData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'copy data into result sheet
    k = 2
    wshMyData.Range("A2:E" & i).Copy wshResult.Range("A" & k)
    k = k + i - 1
    wshBrokersData.Range("A2:E" & j).Copy wshResult.Range("A" & k)
    k = k + j - 2
    'remove duplicates
    wshResult.Range("$A$1:$E$" & k).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 3, 4, 5), Header:=xlYes
    k = wshResult.Range("A" & wshResult.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'start comparison ;)
    'my data
    sTmp = "(" & wshMyData.Name & "!" & wshMyData.Range("B1:B" & i).AddressLocal & "=B2)"
    sTmp = sTmp & "*(" & wshMyData.Name & "!" & wshMyData.Range("C1:C" & i).AddressLocal & "=C2)"
    sTmp = sTmp & "*(" & wshMyData.Name & "!" & wshMyData.Range("D1:D" & i).AddressLocal & "=D2)"
    sTmp = sTmp & "*(" & wshMyData.Name & "!" & wshMyData.Range("E1:E" & i).AddressLocal & "=E2)"
    sTmp = "=SUM(IF(" & sTmp & ", 1, 0))"
    wshResult.Range("F2").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
    wshResult.Range("F2").FormulaArray = sTmp
    wshResult.Range("F2:F" & k).FillDown
    'brokres data
    sTmp = "(" & wshBrokersData.Name & "!" & wshBrokersData.Range("B1:B" & i).AddressLocal & "=B2)"
    sTmp = sTmp & "*(" & wshBrokersData.Name & "!" & wshBrokersData.Range("C1:C" & i).AddressLocal & "=C2)"
    sTmp = sTmp & "*(" & wshBrokersData.Name & "!" & wshBrokersData.Range("D1:D" & i).AddressLocal & "=D2)"
    sTmp = sTmp & "*(" & wshBrokersData.Name & "!" & wshBrokersData.Range("E1:E" & i).AddressLocal & "=E2)"
    sTmp = "=SUM(IF(" & sTmp & ", 1, 0))"
    wshResult.Range("G2").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
    wshResult.Range("G2").FormulaArray = sTmp
    wshResult.Range("G2:G" & k).FillDown
    'autofit
    wshResult.Range("A:G").Columns.AutoFit
  

Exit_CompareData:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wshMyData = Nothing
    Set wshBrokersData = Nothing
    Set wshResult = Nothing
    Set wbk = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_CompareData:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_CompareData

End Sub
```

Result:

[image: result]

As you can see, `0` means that there's no corresponding data in selected sheet.

What above macro does?

1. Adds new sheet: `Result`, then adds column headers (`ID`, `Stock`, `Qty`, `Price`, `Date`, `My data`, `Broker` in row 1 respectively in columns `A`-`G`)
2. Copies all data from your sheet (`Sheet1`) to `Result` sheet
3. Copies all data from broker's sheet (`Sheet2`) to `Result` sheet
4. Removes duplicates in `Result` sheet (based on all columns excluding `ID`)
5. Inserts formula-array in cell `F2` and `G2` and fill it down.

**Important note:** There's at least few other ways to achieve that...

**Final note:** Feel free to change the code to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! It was a fast solution. It works very well. I need now to perform some adjustment to make it work with my files. I'll keep you updated with progress.

Comment: @T.M., i think you wanted to address your comment to Xander ;)